# How to update existing svn (tortoise) to reflect changed project and directory structure whilst maintaining history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to simplify my legacy c# solution down from 5 projects to 3. I want to keep all the relevant source files, but move them around on the local disk to reflect the new project
structures.
SVN repository reflects the old project/directory structure. How best to get svn to reflect this new structure whilst maintaining the revision history of the files? For instance I have a file with path

`c:\workarea\BigSolution\DefunktProj\foo.cs`

with svn path

`trunk/BigSolution/DefunktProj/foo.cs`.

I want to move foo.cs to

`c:\workarea\BigSolution\AliveProj\foo.cs`

and would like svn to see this and maintain the file history.

Comment: Thanks for that illuminating comment. Is there any particular format I could use that would make you come back with an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** both `/DefunktProj` and `/AliveProj` are dirs inside common SVN-repository (and aggregated Working Copy, which include both dirs), you can do it easy: Just reorganize tree, using **only SVN move** for files, not pure Explorer move

[Most forgotten feature](http://tortoisesvn.net/mostforgottenfeature.html) article on TortoiseSVN site explain RClick move in details